# How to take all elements except the first k

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm very new to python and trying to write a concise list-comprehension. Here is what I currently have:

```
def __to_list(i):
    #return some list

k = 3
some_list = #...
result = [e
    for el in some_list
    for e in __to_list(el) if #take all elements in __to_list(el) except the first k]
```

What is the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use slicing.

```
result = some_list[k:]
```

Comment: What about `__to_list`? It's not applied in that case.

Comment: Well you can use it on the return value of that, or wherever you need.

Comment: @St.Antario It doesn't matter how you create the list, you just use this slice to get the part after `k`